# How to read the second-to-last line in a file using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file that has the following as the last three lines. I want to retrieve the penultimate line, i.e. `100.000;8438;  06:46:12`.

```
.
.
.
99.900; 8423;   06:44:41
100.000;8438;   06:46:12
Number of patterns: 8438
```

I don't know the line number. How can I retrieve it using a shell script? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Try this:

```
tail -2 yourfile | head -1
```

Comment: I facepalmed at this obvious answer and the fact I had to search for it...

Comment: this answers seems to be most efficient

Answer (score 6):

A short sed one-liner inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/7671772/5287901

```
sed -n 'x;$p'
```

Explanation:

- `-n` quiet mode: dont automatically print the pattern space
- `x`: exchange the pattern space and the hold space (hold space now store the current line, and pattern space the previous line, if any)
- `$`: on the last line, `p`: print the pattern space (the previous line, which in this case is the penultimate line).

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
tail -2 <filename> | head -1
```

Answer (score 3):

`ed` and `sed` can do it as well.

```
str='
99.900; 8423; 06:44:41
100.000;8438; 06:46:12
Number of patterns: 8438
'

printf '%s' "$str" | sed -n -e '${x;1!p;};h'                     # print last line but one
printf '%s\n' H '$-1p' q | ed -s <(printf '%s' "$str")           # same
printf '%s\n' H '$-2,$-1p' q | ed -s <(printf '%s' "$str")       # print last line but two
```

Answer (score 1):

From: [Useful sed one-liners](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) by Eric Pement

```
# print the next-to-the-last line of a file
sed -e '$!{h;d;}' -e x              # for 1-line files, print blank line
sed -e '1{$q;}' -e '$!{h;d;}' -e x  # for 1-line files, print the line
sed -e '1{$d;}' -e '$!{h;d;}' -e x  # for 1-line files, print nothing
```

You don't need all of them, just pick one.

Answer (score 1):

```
tail +2 <filename>
```

This prints from second line to last line.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what has already been said:

```
ec2thisandthat | sort -k 5 | grep 2012- | awk '{print $2}' | tail -2 | head -1

snap-e8317883
snap-9c7227f7
snap-5402553f
snap-3e7b2c55
snap-246b3c4f
snap-546a3d3f
snap-2ad48241
snap-d00150bb
```

returns

```
snap-2ad48241
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tac <file> | sed -n '2p'
```