# Grep penultimate line

Tags: bash, grep

Like the title says, how can I filter with grep (or similar bash tool) the line-before-the-last-line of a (variable length) file?

That is, show everything EXCEPT the penultimate line.

Thanks

Comment: Why the close vote?  This is a valid beginner's shell programming question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a combination of `head` and `tail` like this for example:

```
$ cat input 
one
two
three
HIDDEN
four
$ head -n -2 input ; tail -n 1 input 
one
two
three
four
```

From the [coreutils head](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#head-invocation) documentation:

> ‘-n k’
>   ‘--lines=k’
>   Output the first k lines. However, if k starts with a ‘-’, print all but the last k lines of each file. Size multiplier suffixes are the same as with the -c option.

So the `head -n -2` part strips all but the last two lines of its input.

This is unfortunately not portable. (POSIX does not allow negative values in the `-n` parameter.)

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that will work too well for for variable length files, without rolling out more code file length.

Comment: Try it. It does work, even with files that contain only one or two lines.

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood the question. This will _not_ work if the input is not plain files but a pipe stream.

Comment: I think the OP made the same mistake here that I did, reading a 2 because in your example "head -n 2" would also sufficed. Clarified it.

Comment: +1. Perhaps mention that `head -n -2` will print all but the last two lines.  Not sure how portable it is to e.g. BSD `head`, though.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` is the wrong tool for this.  You can wing it with something like

```
# Get line count
count=$(wc -l <file)
# Subtract one
penultimate=$(expr $count - 1)
# Delete that line, i.e. print all other lines.
# This doesn't modify the file, just prints
# the requested lines to standard output.
sed "${penultimate}d" file
```

Bash has built-in arithmetic operators which are more elegant than `expr`; but `expr` is portable to other shells.

You could also do this in pure `sed` but I don't want to think about it.  In Perl or awk, it would be easy to print the previous line and then at EOF print the final line.

**Edit:** I thought about `sed` after all.

```
sed -n '$!x;1!p' file
```

In more detail; unless we are at the last line (`$`), exchange the pattern space and the hold space (remember the current line; retrieve the previous line, if any).  Then, unless this is the first line, print whatever is now in the pattern space (the previous line, except when we are on the last line).

Comment: @tripleee, +1 for the *sed* version :)

Answer (score 0):

awk oneliner: (test with seq 10):

```
kent$  seq 10|awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(i!=NR-1)print a[i]}'  
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed`:

```
printf '%s\n' H '$-1d' wq | ed -s file          # in-place file edit
printf '%s\n' H '$-1d' ',p'  wq | ed -s file    # write to stdout
```